Compactness of set of all measurable functions
Let $X$ be compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $Y$ be compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^p$. Consider $\mathcal{F}$ the set of all measurable functions from $X$ to $Y$. Can I find topologies under which $\mathcal{F}$ is compact as well?
I am in particular thinking about topologies of the weak type or metric or norm induced topologies. For instance p-norms seem to be interesting.
So having looked into the weak topology I have come across the following counter-example:
Let $X = Y = [0,1]$. Consider a sequence of functions $f_k:X
\rightarrow Y$ and define
$$f_k(x) = \begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } x \leq \frac{1}{2} \text{ and } k \text{ is odd} \\
0, & \text{if } x \leq \frac{1}{2} \text{ and } k \text{ is even} \\
1 - \frac{1}{k}, & \text{if } x > \frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}$$
Any subsequence does not converge for $x\leq \frac{1}{2}$. So $\mathcal{F}$ cannot be a sequentially compact space under the pointwise topology (which is equivalent to weak topology).
So it seems that not even weak topology can make this set compact. Is there then any hope of making this set compact?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Cross-posted to MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/476361/compactness-of-set-of-measurable-functions-between-compact-subspaces-of-real-num
